# Right click on sheet-tabs disabled in Excel in Project Explorer VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm not getting to remove this sheet from VBA explorer.

Here is some settings:

- That's any protection workbook or sheet activated
- The extension of the file is xlxm

Right click on sheet-tabs disabled in Excel:
[image: Right click on sheet-tabs disabled in Excel]

Comment: They are not available in the main ui as well.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove a sheet in VBE Project Explorer (this is *always* grayed out for sheets).

You must remove the sheet in the tab bar of the Excel GUI.

[image]

```
'             ^ Remove your sheet here by right click and select delete.
```

Note that if your workbook/worksheet is protected you need to unprotect it first:
[Add or remove protection in your document, workbook, or presentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-or-remove-protection-in-your-document-workbook-or-presentation-05084cc3-300d-4c1a-8416-38d3e37d6826)